# Where do these bright edges come from? Principled Shader Cycles SSS

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, subsurface-scattering

I´ve noticed that there are this strange bright edges all around the triangles when using the sss on the standard hard surface Suzanne mesh. Can anyone explain to me how this happens? Is it just a problem between the shader and the geometry?
The same question goes for the dark lines, for example right* to the nose or down-left* to the shadow of the cheek.

*viewer perspective

[image]
*complete*

[image]
*subsurface indirect*

[image]
*subsurface direct*

Comment: Isn't it what SSS shader supposed to do? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/sss.html

Comment: Of course it should produce that effect, but this bright edges look like they´re a bit off. I know from the glossy shader that there are also problems around "perfect" edges. The other thing is, in the example above I´m using the new Principled Shader, so I don´t know if there are any differences between the normal sss and the scattering used in the new setup.